# Is it better to write integration or unit test for Kafka Spring?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-kafka

I've been searching a while about the best way to test Kafka in Spring.
As far as I know, @EmbeddedKafka is more for an unit test but isn't it better to test Kafka in a real working environment by writing integration test for it?
And what really am I testing by writing unit test for Kafka?
A real working producer and consumer should be more meaningful than mocking the kafka.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmbeddedKafka` *is* an integration test. It starts a real broker, not a mock, for you to interact with.

For unit testing, Kafka provides its own mocks for consumer and producer, not reliant on Spring libraries

> what really am I testing by writing unit test for Kafka

Your general processing logic, including error handling and deserialization

In Kafka Streams, you can also control the timing of the records for testing aggregation logic based on simulated windows

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if my producing method doesn't have any business logic inside of it? It just produces data to particular topic, that's all. Should I then write unit test for it?

Comment: @AbduMuhammadal yes, every case is good for tests :)